# Images Won't Load in Safari but will load in FireFox,Chrome,IE

Tags: html, image, safari

I have a slider that is not loading pictures in safari. I don't think it has to do with the slider. I checked the Chrome Emulator and it says there is an error with "Get --image location-- 404 (Not found)". However, in IE, Firefox, Chrome the image is found. I'm not sure where the issue is....

The files were initially in jpg, then I saved them as png (this made the files much larger). I had one that had a file name "laser.jpg" that when I changed it to "laser.png" and changed the corresponding code it worked.

Is there something about the file names that could cause a problem? (Does it not render capital letters vs not?) All of my other .jpg and .png files load perfectly.

Is this more related to image resolution for Safari? I read somewhere that safari has a memory load limit, is this what I'm running into?

The images are 72 dpi and are 1000 pixels in width.

> img class="sp-image" data-default="images/sIMG4826.png" data-retina="images/IMG4826.png" src="images/IMG4826.png" style="width: auto; height: 100%; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px;"

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to place higher resolution images for the Retina Display users, but it was causing issues. 

If you run into this. Just use the same resolution image as you would for any other computer.